# Extended continuous function

Tags: general-topology

Suppose $X$ and $Y$ and two metric space and $Y$ be complete metric space if $f$ is function from $A$ to $Y$ and $f$ is uniformly continuous, then $f$ can be uniquely extended to a function $g$ from Cl(A) to $Y$.

My attempted

Let $x\in Cl(A)$ then there exist a sequence $x_n$ in $A$  converges to $x$ since any converge sequence is Cauchy sequences the $x_n$ is Cauchy sequences since $f$ is uniformly continuous then $f(x_n)$ is Cauchy sequences but $Y$ is complete metric then it is converge to $f(x)$ in $Y$. So, there exists such $y\in Y$ such that $f(x)=y$.

So, wethere or not my solution is correct? any help will appreciate Kd

Comment: Have you already proven that uniformly continuous functions take Cauchy sequences to Cauchy sequences? This is really the main point, and it doesn't hold for merely continuous functions. (The standard counterexample to the conclusion of this result is $f : (0,1) \to \mathbb{R},f(x)=1/x$.)

Comment: Basically just define $g$ as $f$ on the interior and as $g(x) =$ limit $f(x_n)$ where $x_n \to x,$ $x$ in the closure.  Then show this is unique.

Comment: For uniqueness is okay I did, but I am not entirely sure about my solution